# Why UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext isn't correct?

Tags: events, touch, cgcontext

Can you help me ??
Something in my touches event doesn't work correctly. 
My painting area has 900 x 700px, isn't the complete UIView.
In the console error show me:

```
  CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
  CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0
  CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0......
  .......
  .......
```

Why UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext isn't correct ??

how can i fix this error

My code:

```
- (void)**touchesMoved**:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

mouseSwiped = YES;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.tempDrawImage];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tempDrawImage.frame.size);
[self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tempDrawImage.frame.size.width, self.tempDrawImage.frame.size.height)];

CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastPoint = currentPoint;
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before Look at this link:
[invalid context error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570846/why-there-is-an-invalid-context-error).

I have subclassed the view and put my code in drawRect method and it worked for me.