# MBProgressHUD Giving strange sporadic NSLog errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

The following method in MBProgressHUD.m produces a weird NSLog Error that is only seen sporadically. The app never crashes, I just get this message in NSLog sometimes. The NSLog message is posted below also.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    if (self.dimBackground) {
        //Gradient colours
        size_t gradLocationsNum = 2;
        CGFloat gradLocations[2] = {0.0f, 1.0f};
        CGFloat gradColors[8] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.75f}; 
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradColors, gradLocations, gradLocationsNum);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        //Gradient center
        CGPoint gradCenter= CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
        //Gradient radius
        float gradRadius = MIN(self.bounds.size.width , self.bounds.size.height) ;
        //Gradient draw
        CGContextDrawRadialGradient (context, gradient, gradCenter,
                                     0, gradCenter, gradRadius,
                                     kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    }

    // Set background rect color
    if (self.color) {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.color.CGColor);
    } else {
        CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 0.0f, self.opacity);
    }


    // Center HUD
    CGRect allRect = self.bounds;
    // Draw rounded HUD backgroud rect
    CGRect boxRect = CGRectMake(roundf((allRect.size.width - size.width) / 2) + self.xOffset,
                                roundf((allRect.size.height - size.height) / 2) + self.yOffset, size.width, size.height);
    float radius = 10.0f;
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(boxRect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(boxRect));
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(boxRect) - radius, CGRectGetMinY(boxRect) + radius, radius, 3 * (float)M_PI / 2, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(boxRect) - radius, CGRectGetMaxY(boxRect) - radius, radius, 0, (float)M_PI / 2, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(boxRect) + radius, CGRectGetMaxY(boxRect) - radius, radius, (float)M_PI / 2, (float)M_PI, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(boxRect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(boxRect) + radius, radius, (float)M_PI, 3 * (float)M_PI / 2, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

The NSLog message:

> Error: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is
>   a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
>   invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation
>   of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570846/why-there-is-an-invalid-context-error) SO answer, but to be honest I don't really understand it. And seeing as how this is a commonly used 3rd party library, I was surprised I couldn't find anyone else discussing this issue specifically in relation to MBProgressHUD.

Comment: This maybe a stupid question, but are you using `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor:` anywhere else in your application? That error usually occurs when the `context` you pass to `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor:` is nil, which doesn't look to be the case in the sample code above.