# A very scary message from iOS

Tags: objective-c

Lately i am sometimes getting this very strange message during operation of my app, with no crash.
(mainly the app now just get images from the net ) .
I thing it has to do with me drawing a rect around image , the message is :

```
<Error>: CGContextStrokeRect: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

the rect drawing :

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithBorderFromImage:(UIImage*)source
{

    CGSize size = [source size];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [source drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,(255/255.f),(255/255.f),(255/255.f), 1.0);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return testImg;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `[source size]` is possibly occasionally `CGSizeZero` - put a check in and return `nil`.

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithBorderFromImage:(UIImage*)source
{
    CGSize size = [source size];

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(size, CGSizeZero)) {
        return nil;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [source drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,(255/255.f),(255/255.f),(255/255.f), 1.0);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return testImg;
}
```

You can simiplify your above code by the way using the newer non-CG methods - this shows that you do not need to use `CGContext` directly...

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithBorderFromImage:(UIImage*)source
{
    CGSize size = [source size];

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(size, CGSizeZero)) {
        return nil;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [source drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
    UIRectFrame(rect);
    UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return testImg;
}
```

EDIT: I've also made your methods class methods as there is no reason to use an instance method - unless you want to call `[source imageWithBoarder]` instead - in my opinion this is a bit neater :)

Comment: thanks a lot.  i am very doubt that the source size is zero. i can see the image in my eyes when it happens ,so i guess it has a size>0 ??

Answer (score 2):

The call to `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` is probably returning `nil`.

As for your stated goal though, I think you would be better off skipping the CoreGraphics drawing route, and instead putting your `UIImage` in a `UIImageView`. If you're trying to give it a border, assign the `UIImageView`'s `layer.borderWidth` and `layer.borderColor` properties some values. Taken out of context though, it's tough to see what you're doing, so this may/may not be the solution to your problem.

Comment: I prefer this approach if he just wants a border - otherwise he's creating an image each time just to put a line around! :(

Answer (score 1):

I would highly discourage you from using the method you're using. Drawing images yourself is verbose, error prone and less maintainable. Instead, I recommend you use an `UIImageView`. You can then place your drawing code within the `UIImageView`'s `drawRect` method [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2570941/632736). Otherwise, your graphics context will be `nil`.

Performing drawing outside of the `drawRect` method is highly discouraged.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i read your link, but what does it means? just to set a method drawRect and put it inside? or do i have to find it somewhere? i want to have a method which get an image and returned it with a rect.

Comment: @Curnelious All ojects that get drawn onto the screen draw themselves and their contents. They have a `drawRect` method for this purpose. In this case, you're wanting to draw a border around the image. It makes the most sense for the image to draw that itself, since it will know it's own bounds. Because of this, you should place these drawing calls inside of the `UIImage`'s `drawRect` method. This will ensure that every time the object is redrawn, the object will redraw its border as well. You will overriding the `drawRect` method so you will need to call super's implementation.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer He's creating a context so his method is fine - what is probably the problem is the `size` of the context.

Comment: @Rich Borders and such need to be drawn in the `drawRect` method. Otherwise, they're not persisted when the object is inevitably redrawn.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer no, if you use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` you are creating a new context. He is drawing into that context and then obtaining an `UIImage` from it.

Comment: @Rich Most likely, you are both correct. Passing a size of {0.0f,0.0f} to ```UIGraphicsBeginImageContext``` will not create an context. So, the context is NULL, but due to the fact that the rect being passed doesn't have any size.

Comment: @TaylorHalliday indeed - the only issue I have is with the incorrect statements made above :)